# Why google asks MD5 instead of SHA1?

Tags: google-maps, md5, sha

I am trying develop an Android app which uses Google maps. So for the maps APIkey, I read the document and got the MD5 fingerprint.

While searching the procedure to get MD5 fingerprint, I came to know that SHA1 is more secure than MD5, If it is right then why google uses MD5 instead of SHA1.

Comment: Are you claiming that someone could generate a valid signing certificate with a colliding MD5 sum before the Maps API is deprecated in however many years?

Comment: Sorry dear, what you are saying is not understandable to me as I am very new to this. So can you please explain a little briefly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the MD5 is not used for a security reason but for the uniqueness of your app.
The probability to get a colision with an other key is very low.